# Convert a comma-separated value string into a list and convert all its value and keys into integer or float using comprehension

Tags: python

suppose we have a list of list called `A`:

```
A = "1, 200, 1.9;2, 450, 8.2 ;2, 350, 0.3"
```

What I want to do are convert string above into a dictionary with first element as key and second as value, and after that I want to convert first and second element to `int` and the third to `float`.

So it will be as follows:

```
A = [[1, 200, 1.9],
     [2, 450, 8.2],
     [3, 350, 0.3]]
```

With first and second element converted to `int` and the last to `float`

I tried  list comprehension for this:

```
A = list([int(a), int(b), float(c) for a, b, c in row.split(',')] for row in A.split(';'))
```

Got `SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax` Error on it:
Any helps really appreciated

Comment: The inner list comprehension doesn't make sense. If the value in a list comp is a tuple you need parentheses, `[(int(a), int(b), float(c)) for a, b, c in row.split(',')]`, but that's not actually what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You state "convert string above to dictionary with first element as key and second as value" but the result requested is not a dictionary with keys/values but a list of lists.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[float(q) if "." in q else int(q) for q in i.split(",")] for i in A.split(";")]
```

**output**

```
[[1, 200, 1.9], 
[2, 450, 8.2], 
[2, 350, 0.3]]
```

Comment: nice answer, but we can't explicitly convert the specific elements. it only convert when the conditions met

Comment: your saying you want them parsed based on index? try this `[[ int(q.split(",")[i]) if i < 2 else float(q.split(",")[2]) for i in range(3)] for q in A.split(";")]`

Comment: or `[[int(i) for i in q.split(",")[:2]]+[float(q.split(",")[2])] for q in A.split(";")]`

Answer (score 0):

Code like `[1,2, c for c in range(2)]` is invalid syntax because it is ambiguous and can mean any of these:

1. `[1,2,(0,1)]`
2. `[1,(2,0), (2,1)]`
3. `[(1,2,0), (1,2,1)]`

It's impossible to tell what is meant by this code, so you have to be more specific.

To get any of these variants, construct the tuple explicitly:

1. `[1,2, tuple(c for c in range(2))]`
2. `[1, *((2, c) c for c in range(2))]`
3. `[(1, 2, c) c for c in range(2)]`

You probably want the last one, so that'd be:

```
[(int(a), int(b), float(c)) for a, b, c in row.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but:

```
A = "1, 200, 1.9;2, 450, 8.2 ;2, 350, 0.3"
A = [(lambda a,b,c:[int(a),int(b),float(c)])(*x.split(',')) for x in A.split(';')]
print(A)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 200, 1.9], [2, 450, 8.2], [2, 350, 0.3]]
```

For more readability:

```
A = "1, 200, 1.9;2, 450, 8.2 ;2, 350, 0.3"

def convert(item):
    a,b,c = item.split(',')
    return [int(a),int(b),float(c)]

A = [convert(item) for item in A.split(';')]
print(A)
```